# Extension protobuf

Tags: grpc, google-protobuf, protoc

Есть такой файл test_message.proto

```
// Protocol version: v.2.5.0
syntax = "proto2";

message TestMessage {
    required string id = 1;

    // Extensions.
    extensions 100 to 9999;
}
```

сообщение в json из которого выглядит так:

```
{
   "id":"id_str"
}
```

Мне нужно добавить расширение к этому сообщению чтобы поддерживался такой json:

```
{
   "id":"id_str",
   "ext": {
      "ext_field_1":"string_value"
   }
}
```

в отдельном файле test_message_ext.proto я пишу расширение:

```
syntax = "proto2";
import "test_message.proto";

message TestMessageExt {
    optional string ext_field_1 = 1;
}

extend TestMessage {
    optional TestMessageExt ext = 201;
}
```

запускаю `protoc --python_out=. ./*.prot`

и пытаюсь распарсить расширенный json

```
import test_message_pb2
import test_message_ext_pb2
from google.protobuf import json_format

    
file = open("./msg.json")
msgJson = file.read()
msg = test_message_pb2.TestMessage()
json_format.Parse(msgJson,msg)
print(msg.id)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Message type "TestMessage" has no field named "ext" at "TestMessage".
 Available Fields(except extensions): "['id']"
```

Вопрос: что нужно поменять что бы распарсить json в protobuf?